# user's progress analysis laravel

Tags: laravel, analytics

I'm Building a pool of question, and I would like to give users the option to view their "performance".
I'm trying to figure out how exactly to do it, because I want it to help the users track their studying progress.

Different options came to my mind:

- Track each user time on the website (aka time spent solving questions/learning), with this I can:

  1. Show a number = average time spent learning per day.
  2. Show a graph of daily usage till today.
     I imagine it involves creating a "time" table for each user, each row would be representing a single day (from day 0 where they registered) and  it would include one column that would be the time spent on a particular day. So if a user logs in at 8am and logs out at 10am this number would then increase to 2.0, then if he logs in back at 4pm untill 7:30pm it would add to the time spent 3.5 so in total it would be 5.5. Since it doesn't involves user interaction, it's good in a way.
- Put a checkbox in each question so if a user checks it (=means that he solved the question)

  1. I can keep track on how many questions a user solved and present this information (like precentage of solved questions out of the total questions or daily amount of questions he solved each day).

This sounds easier to implement, but it involves users actually checking boxes which I assume they won't do because its easier not to check these boxes, which I don't blame them :)

How would you implement the above options? if it's a complex solution than I might as well give up on that.

Any suggestions of how to track a user progress that I didn't think of?

Answer (score 0):

You can look how other application do that. For example in Duolingo, every time you accomplish some task your XP is rising. So you can maybe follow same schema.

[image: Duolingo]

Another application you can look is Laracast, there you getting some badges and this make your progress and level increase.

[image: Laracast]

Comment: In my website, users see the questions on the screen and solve them outside the website with pen & paper..